# Is there a way to get all the subfolder name from a folder of container from azure blob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to fetch all virtual directory name from red circle of image

[image: hierarchy]

Comment: Azure Blob storage don't have folder, They are virtual directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp43
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=1123bowman;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            string folder_main = "test1";
            List<string> subs3 = new List<string>();
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            string containerName = "test";
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix:folder_main);
            foreach (var blob in blobs) {
                //Console.WriteLine(blob.Name);
                string[] sub_names = blob.Name.Split('/');
                if (sub_names.Length>2&&!subs3.Contains(sub_names[1]))
                {
                    subs3.Add(sub_names[1]);
                }
            }
            foreach (var sub3 in subs3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sub3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Original Answer:**

Azure Blob storage don't have folder, They are virtual directories.

For your requirement, you can parse the file name based on the code to get the 'folder' you mentioned.

Comment: I want to fetch all virtual directories name

Comment: @SaurabhSunil. I have updated the answer. if `Virtual directory1` has some sub folders, do you want to get the these sub folders?

Comment: Thanks @BowmanZhu. No, Virtual directory1 have some files and I want to get those files

Comment: What should  I do to copy all files data into a byte array. Like in case of local directory we use -  var ByteArrayList = Directory.GetFiles(dir).Select(File.ReadAllBytes).ToList();

Comment: @SaurabhSunil. Do you mean the files on blob storage?

Comment: If you mean that, just convert stream to bytes

Comment: yes right, the files on blob storage, I want to copy all the content of file into a byte array.

Comment: @SaurabhSunil. When you down the blob, the type is string, so just convert string to bytes []